# 100% height XUL elements

Tags: firefox, layout, xul

I have this deck in a Firefox sidebar (XUL):

```
<deck id="mydeck" selectedIndex="0">

  <vbox id="myscreen1">
    ...
  </vbox>

  <vbox id="myscreen2">
    <vbox flex="3" minheight="150">
      ...
    </vbox>
    <splitter collapse="after" resizeafter="farthest">
      <grippy height="10" align="end" />
    </splitter>
    <vbox flex="1" minheight="125">
      ...
    </vbox>
  </vbox>

</deck>
```

I'm trying to get `#myscreen2` to take up the whole sidebar vertically. How do I achieve this?

Right now it only uses the minimum height set for the two boxes. I've tried to set `height: 100%` and `flex="1"` on the deck itself and `#myscreen2`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't like the available XUL documentation, but I managed to come up with a solution:

```
<deck id="mydeck" selectedIndex="0" flex="1">

  <vbox id="myscreen1">
    ...
  </vbox>

  <vbox id="myscreen2">
    <vbox flex="3" minheight="150">
      ...
    </vbox>
    <splitter collapse="after" resizeafter="farthest">
      <grippy height="10" align="end" />
    </splitter>
    <vbox flex="1" minheight="125">
      ...
    </vbox>
  </vbox>

</deck>
```

The key was to have `flex="1"` on the deck. Not sure why it wasn't working when I tried it the first time.